# Google Cloud Storage for Google Colab TPU pricing

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-colaboratory, tpu

I want to use Google Colab free TPU with a custom dataset, that's why I need to upload it to GCS. I created bucket in GCS and uploaded dataset.

Also I read that there are two classes of operations with data in GCS: operation class A and operation class B [[reference]](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing#operations-pricing).

My questions are: does accessing dataset from GCS in Google Colab fall in one of these operation classes? What is average price you pay for using GCS for Colab TPU?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because is custom support question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, accessing to the Objects (files) in your GCS bucket will result in possible charges to your Billing Account but there are some other factors that you might need to consider. Let me explain (sorry in advance for the very long answer):

Google Cloud Platform services use APIs *behind the scene* to perform multiple actions such as show, create, delete or edit certain resources.

Cloud Storage is not the Exception. As mentioned in the [Cloud Storage docs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing#operations-by-class) operations can be cataloged in two: the ones performed by the JSON API and the ones done by the XML API.

All operations performed on the Cloud Console or [Client libraries](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries) (the ones used to interact via code with languages like Python, Java, PHP, etc.), the Operations will be charged using the JSON API by default. Let's focus on this one.

I want you to pay attention at the name of the methods under each *Operations* column:

[image]

The structure can be read as follows:

```
service.resource.action
```

Since all these methods are related to the Cloud Storage service, it is normal to see the *storage* service in all of them.

In *Operations B* column, the first method is `storage.*.get`. There is no other *get method* in the other columns which means that retrieving information from a bucket (read metadata) or objects (read a file via code, download files, etc.) inside a bucket will be considered as part of this method.

Before talking about how to calculate costs let me add: Google Cloud Storage not only charges you for the action itself but also for the size of the file traveling among the Network. Here are the 2 most common scenarios:

1. You are interacting with the files from another GCP service. Since it uses the internal GCP network, charges are not that big. If you decide to go with this, I would recommend to use resources (App Engine, Compute Engine, Kubernetes Engine, etc.) in the same location to avoid additional charges. Please check the [Network egress charges within GCP](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing#network-buckets).
2. You are interacting from an environment outside GCP. This is the scenario where you are interacting with other services like Google Colab (even when it is a Google service, it is outside the Cloud Platform). Please see the [General network usage pricing](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing#network-egress) for Cloud Storage.

Now, let's talk about the [Storage classes](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/storage-classes), which can also affect the object's availability and pricing. Depending on where the bucket is created, you will be charged for the amount of stored Data as mentioned in [the docs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing#storage-pricing).

Even when the Nearline, Coldline and Archive classes is the cheapest ones regarding storage, they charge you an extra for [retrieving data](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing#archival-pricing). This is because these classes are meant to be used to store data that is infrequently.

I think we have covered everything and we can move now to the important question: **How much all of this will cost?** It depends on your files' size, the times you interact with them and the Storage class of your bucket.

Let's say that you have 1 Standard bucket in North America with your Dataset of 20 GB and you read it from Google Colab 10 times a day we can calculate the following:

Standard Storage: $0.020 per GB

```
$0.020 * 20 = $0.4USD
```

Class B operations (per 10,000 operations) for Standard operations: $0.004

```
Given that you are only charged $0.004 per 10,000 we can say that each operation 
costs $0.0000004 USD so 10 operations will be $0.000004 USD.
```

Egress to Worldwide Destinations (excluding Asia & Australia): $0.12 per GB

```
$0.12 * 20 because it is the size of our file = $2.4 USD 
10 times we are reading this doc per day: 2.4 * 10 = $24 USD
```

Given this example, you would pay per day: **0.4 + 0.000004 + 24 = $24.400004 USD**. Another example can be found in the [Pricing overview section](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing#pricing)

And finally the good news, Google Cloud Storage offers [Always Free usage limits](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing#cloud-storage-always-free) that reset every month. I am attaching the table from that link below:

[image]

This means that: if  during a whole month you store less than 5 GBs in a Standard class bucket, you perform less than 50,000 Class B operations, less than 5,000 Class A Operations and you sent less than 1GB over the Network, you won't pay a thing.

Once you pass those limits, the charges will start i.e. If you have a Dataset of 15GB, you will only be charged for 10GB.